# Session timeout when uploading a big file to S3 via AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm new to Amazon Cloud and I've got a problem.

I want to upload a 7 Go file to S3 using the AWS management console. I created a bucket, succeeded in uploading 2 small files, so I tried to upload my big file.

When I went out yesterday evening, it was still in progress (13%) but when I arrived this morning I had this error : "Your session has expired for your security " so my upload had failed

Can someone advise me something to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [command-line tools](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html) rather than the console. You should also add a lifecycle rule to abort multi-part uploads after some reasonable amount of time (2-3 days, probably).

Answer (score 0):

From the S3 FAQ:

> Q: How much data can I store?
>
> The total volume of data and number of objects you can store are
>   unlimited. Individual Amazon S3 objects can range in size from a
>   minimum of 0 bytes to a maximum of 5 terabytes. The largest object
>   that can be uploaded in a single PUT is 5 gigabytes. For objects
>   larger than 100 megabytes, customers should consider using the
>   Multipart Upload capability.

Im guessing `7 Go` was supposed to be `7 GB`?

Could the timeout be related to your file size?

Comment: The problem that the upload takes a long time more than 12 hours and the session exipred less than 12 hours so iI can't upload the file

Comment: Right. It may also be too large. You are probably going to have to find a better connection to upload anything that large if there is a automatic timeout.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot You're just teaching me all sort of stuff here. Thanks!